# Android Group Notification with buttons

Tags: android

Is it possible to make an expand notifications with buttons.
In Gmail notification, if multiple notifications are received , only One will be displayed in the notification tray with total count. If we expand , it display other notification line by line. I know how to write it.

My problem is with notifications with button, I want to display it similar to gmail.that is, if multiple notifications are received , only One will be displayed in the notification tray with total count,If we expand , it should  display other notification one by one just like a list view , each notification should have buttons.......Please help how can I do this,P Lease post some sample code

Comment: Did you ever look at this? http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html

Comment: As I have mentioned in my question I need to create expandable notification with buttons for each notification. IN your link, each single notification has only one line that can be added using addLine

Comment: You can see the example of expandable notifications and you can add Actions(Buttons) in my link. As I understand, you want notifications like that http://developer.android.com/images/android-5.0/notifications/action_combo.png I get this image url from the link I have mentioned before.  For multiple notifications you must use different ids for each notification.

Comment: When multiple notifications come,  I want to display all in a group rather than separate notifications , it should look like a single notification and if expand , should display all with buttons on each